# How to convert string with timezone string to datetime?

Tags: python, datetime, timezone

I have a string like this: `'2005-01-03 16:00:00:000 America/New_York'`, the simplest way to convert it to a datetime instance I could come up with is as below:

```
ts=r'2005-01-03 16:00:00:000 America/New_York'
import re
pos=re.match(r'[\d\- :]*', ts).end()
tzs=ts[pos:]
tss=ts[:pos-5]
from pytz import timezone
tz=timezone(tzs)
from dateutil import parser
dt=parser.parse(tss)
d=tz.localize(dt)
print d

#2005-01-03 16:00:00-05:00
```

which is too complicated I think....

So is there any simpler way to achieve this? Thx in advance ~

Answer (score 4, accepted):

How about:

```
import datetime
import pytz

ts = '2005-01-03 16:00:00:000 America/New_York'
tPart, tzPart = ts.rsplit(' ', 1)
dt = datetime.datetime.strptime(tPart, "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S:%f")
tz = pytz.timezone(tzPart)
d = tz.localize(dt)
```

Comment: you could use `timestr, space, tzname = ts.rpartition(' ')`. You could pass `is_dst=None` to `tz.localize()` to assert that the local time is not ambiguous or non-existent.

Comment: @J.F.Sebastian Thanks.  What is the advantage of `rpartition` over `rsplit`?

Comment: `.rpartition()` always returns 3 values, `.rsplit(, 1)` may return one or two values.